# Call 1 jersey resource class from another Jersey resource class with @Context ServletContext

Tags: class, resources, jersey

I have Jersey resource class A calling a method in resource class B.Both classes have a @Context ServletContext servletContext at the class level. When I instantiate class B to call it from resource class A using its empty constructor, servletContext  is null in the class B method being called. Is there any Jersey framework way I can call class B and yet have the servletContext retain its values/attributes from class A.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can instantiate class B using ResourceContext. I.e. in class A you can have:

```
@Context private ResourceContext rc;
```

And then in you can instantiate resource B as follows:

```
B resourceB = rc.getResource(B.class);
```

See [ResourceContext javadoc](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/javax/ws/rs/container/ResourceContext.html) for more info.

Comment: Here is the updated location for the [JavaDoc](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/javax/ws/rs/container/ResourceContext.html) in the answer