# is it possible to call one jax-rs method from another?

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs

suppose i have some jax-rs resource class:

```
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class ResourceA {
   @GET
   public Something get(@Context UriInfo uriInfo) {
      if (...) {
         //how to get to ResourceB ?
      }
   }
}
```

and i want to conditionally redirect the call to some other jax-rs resource:

```
public class ResourceB {
   @GET
   @Path("{identifier}")
   public Other get(@PathParam("identifier")String someArg) {
   }
}
```

how do i do this? 
note that i dont want this to be visible to the client (so no http redirects) and generally the resource methods i want to redirect to dont share the same signature (they may have path params etc as in the example i gave).

im running jersey 2.6 under apache tomcat (its a spring app, if thats any help)

**EDIT** - im looking for a jax-rs equivalent of [servlet forward](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#forward%28javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse%29). i dont want to do an extra http hop or worry abour instantiating resource classes myself

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can get it using ResourceContext as follows:

```
@Context 
ResourceContext resourceContext;
```

This will inject the ResourceContext into your Resource. You then get the resource you want using:

```
ResourceB b = resourceContext.getResource(ResourceB.class);
```

The [Javadoc for ResourceContext is here](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/javax/ws/rs/container/ResourceContext.html). You can find a [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6944500/call-1-jersey-resource-class-from-another-jersey-resource-class-with-context-se)

Answer (score 6):

I'm not aware of any possibility to do this from a resource method, but if it fits your use case, what you could do is implement your redirect logic in a pre matching request filter, for example like so:

```
@Provider
@PreMatching
public class RedirectFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) {
        UriInfo uriInfo = requestContext.getUriInfo();
        String prefix = "/redirect";
        String path = uriInfo.getRequestUri().getPath();
        if (path.startsWith(prefix)) {
            String newPath = path.substring(prefix.length());
            URI newRequestURI = uriInfo.getBaseUriBuilder().path(newPath).build();
            requestContext.setRequestUri(newRequestURI);
        }
    }
}
```

This will redirect every request to `/redirect/some/resource` to `/some/resource` (or whatever you pass to `requestContext.setRequestUri()`) internally, before the resource method has been matched to the request and is executed and without http redirects or an additional internal http request.

Comment: nice suggestion, but unfortunately for me my routing logic depends on values calculated inside the resource method (from arguments/request body values etc) so i cant perform the redirection before.

Comment: @radai Gotcha, too bad. Note that you can access path and query parameters in a filter via UriInfo, but not form parameters/the request body (without consuming the body afaik).

Comment: With CXF note that you need to use resource URI. ie `setRequestUri(new Uri("/path/to/other"))` (found in `@Path("/path/to/other")`) not the absolute URI. For example the above code in this answer don't work with CXF (2.7.18).