# Call a resource method of a Controller from within another

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

This is related to the question: 
[is it possible to call one jax-rs method from another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22280127/is-it-possible-to-call-one-jax-rs-method-from-another) but in terms of Spring-Boot.

Is it possible to call a resource method of a Controller from within another resource method of an another Controller ?

So, if I have 2 controllers:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/foo")
public class FooController {

    @RequestMapping("bar")
    public BarController printBarVersion() {

    }
}

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/taz")
public class BarController {

    @RequestMapping("print")
    public static void getBarVersion() {
        System.out.println("Version 1");
    }
}
```

Is it possible to call getBarVersion from within printBarVersion method ? What would the URL look like in that case ?

Comment: you can call any method from `printBarVersion` => you can call `getBarVersion` by eg. `@Autowire BarController bc`. URL is just the normal one for `printBarVersion` .i.e. `/foo/bar`. Or what do you mean by "call"?

Comment: Call is indeed calling the method getBarVersion. I know the URL call for printBarVersion is /foo/bar. What I need to know is, from printBarVersion, is it possible to call getBarVersion by specifying just /print ?

Comment: what's wrong with `bc.getBarVersion()`?