# REST call invoking Another REST call in jax rs and Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, jax-rs

I should call one Rest call with some json payload after this it should invoke one more end point with the same payload (POST) call and it should give some response. I should capture that response .

How can I do that using Jax rs and Spring?

Comment: Refer this it has some nice examples..https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot2/resttemplate/spring-restful-client-resttemplate-example/

Comment: Possible Duplicates: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6944500/call-1-jersey-resource-class-from-another-jersey-resource-class-with-context-se, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22280127/is-it-possible-to-call-one-jax-rs-method-from-another